# Understanding Brackets in Dart

Tags: dart

I have many confusion about **Brackets** in **Dart**(Flutter).
Which **bracket** "(), {}, []" is used for what?

Comment: Have you read the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)?

Comment: Yes. But still not clear.

Comment: () - functions, [] - arrays, {} - objects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Parentheses: `()`

- Group expressions:

  ```dart
  var x = (1 + 2) * 3;
  ```

  or can designate parameter lists for functions:

  ```dart
  var getAnswer = () => 42;

  int square(int x) => x * x;
  ```
- Or can designate [function calls](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators) (including calls to a `.call` method on [callable classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes)):

  ```dart
  var answer = getAnswer();
  var squared = square(4);
  ```
- Or is part of the syntax to some keywords.  This includes (but is not limited to) `if`, `assert`, `for`, `while`, `switch`, `catch`:

  ```dart
  if (condition) {
    ...
  }

  assert(condition);

  for (var item in collection) {
    ...
  }

  while (condition) {
    ...
  }

  switch (value) {
    ...
  }

  try {
    ...
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    ...
  }
  ```
- In Dart 3, specifies a [*record*](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/records/records-feature-specification.md):

  ```dart
  var emptyRecord = ();
  var singleField = (123,);
  var namedFields = (123, foo: 456);
  ```

### Square brackets: `[]`

- By itself, creates [`List` literals](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists):

  ```dart
  var list = [1, 2, 3];
  var emptyList = []; // Creates a List<dynamic>.
  ```
- When used on an object, calls [`operator []`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators) or `operator []=`, which usually accesses or sets an element of a collection respectively:

  ```dart
  var element = list[index];
  var value = map[key];

  list[index] = element;
  map[key] = value;
  ```
- In a parameter list, specifies [optional *positional* parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#positional-parameters):

  ```dart
  int function(int x, [int y, int z]) {
    return x + y ?? 0 + z ?? 0;
  }

  function(1, 2);
  ```
- [In dartdoc comments, creates linked references](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#documentation-comments) to other symbols:

  ```dart
  /// Creates a [Bar] from a [Foo].
  Bar fooToBar(Foo foo) {
    // ...
  }
  ```

### Curly braces: `{}`

- Can create a block of code, grouping lines together and limiting variable scope.  This includes (but is not limited to) function bodies, class declarations, `if`-`else` blocks, `try`-`catch` blocks, `for` blocks, `while` blocks, `switch` blocks, etc.:

  ```dart
  class Class {
    int member;
  }

  void doNothing() {}

  void function(bool condition) {
    {
      String x = 'Hello world!';
      print(x);
    }

    if (condition) {
      int x = 42; // No name collision due to separate scopes.
      print(x);
    }
  }
  ```
- By itself, can create [`Set`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets) or [`Map` literals](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps):

  ```dart
  var set = {1, 2, 3};
  var emptySet = <int>{};

  var map = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3};
  var emptyMap = {}; // Creates a Map<dynamic, dynamic>
  ```
- In a parameter list, specifies [*named* parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-parameters):

  ```dart
  int function(int x, {required int y, int? z}) {
    return x + y + z ?? 0;
  }

  function(1, y: 2);
  ```
- Creates enumerations:

  ```dart
  enum SomeEnumeration {
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
  }
  ```
- In `String`s can be used to disambiguate interpolated expressions:

  ```dart
  var foo = 'foo';
  var foobar = '${foo}bar';

  var s = '${function(1, 2)}';
  ```
- Or in `String`s is used to specify Unicode code points with more than 4 hexadecimal digits:

  ```
  var bullseye = '\u{1F3AF}'; //
  ```

## Angle brackets: `<>`

- When used as a pair in function or class declarations, creates [generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics):

  ```dart
  class GenericClass<T> {
    T member;
  }

  T function<T>(T x) {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Or specifies explicit types when *using* generics:

  ```dart
  var map = <String, int>{};
  ```

---

Note that the above does not include the meaning of `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and `<>` when used in `RegExp` patterns.  Regular expression syntax is its own language and isn't Dart-specific.

Comment: For parentheses what about syntax like: ‘’’ onTap: () { setState ( () { count ++;}); ‘’’ what are these floating () ???

Comment: @YogeshRiyat Those are empty parameter lists for anonymous functions.  I already mentioned that in this answer ("or can designate parameter lists for functions").