# what is multi round brackets mean in flutter ((){})()?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 (() {
                        if (done && !operate) {
                          return x;
                        } else if (operate)
                          return y;
                        else {
                          return z;
                        }

                      })(),
```

what are (() {} )() mean and how, when should I use It ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61947930/.  In the case of `(() {})()`: `() {}` creates an anonymous function that takes no arguments and that has an empty body, the set of parentheses around it is used for grouping, and then the last `()` invokes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function assigned to a variable:

```
var myFunc = () { ... };
```

You can call it like this:

```
myFunc();
```

---

This is an anonymous function:

```
() { ... }
```

Sadly, it is not assigned to a variable and has no name. So, this is how you can call this function:

```
(() { ... })() // Wrap the function in parenthesis and call it.
```

---

> how, when should I use It ?

If you are too lazy to make a function (or can't decide on a good name) and you are sure that you are going to use it only once, You can use this.

It may seem pretty useless because there is no code reusability offered here but, it can be helpful when building widgets.

Consider a scenario:

```
Widget1(
    child: Widget2(
        child: Widget3(
            child:
```

Suppose, you want a child for Widget3 which depends on a variable *x* which can have multiple values..

You can do like this:

```
child: x == 0 ? WidgetA() : (x == 1? WidgetB() : (x == 3 ? WidgetC() : ...))
```

It's complex. You probably don't want to do that!

Instead you might want,

```
child: ((){
    switch(x) {
        case 0:
            return WidgetA();
        case 1:
            return WidgetB();
        case 2:
            return WidgetC();
        .....
    }
})()
```

This looks way more cleaner. Of course, it's not a good option at all if you want to reuse this function somewhere else but if you are sure that this is the only place, then you can make an anonymous function like this and call it in place.