# How to pass an object AND a callback to a Stateless Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to pass an object together with a Call Back to a stateless widget but fail to do so, can anyone help?

```
child: NnewPage(rec, onSelectParam: (int param) {
            print('value: ' + param.toString());
        })

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
   NewPage(this.rec, this.onSelectParam);
   
   var rec;
   Function(int) onSelectParam;
```

It gives compile error:

> Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.

Comment: Use parameter label, NewPage(rec: Object, onSelectParam: handleCallback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

```
child: NnewPage(rec, (param) {
        print('value: ' + param.toString());
    })

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
   NewPage(this.rec, this.onSelectParam);
   
   var rec;
   Function(int) onSelectParam;
```

or:

```
child: NnewPage(rec: rec, onSelectParam: (param) {
            print('value: ' + param.toString());
    })

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
   NewPage({this.rec, this.onSelectParam});
   
   var rec;
   Function(int) onSelectParam;
```

For more detail, you can read this article: [Understanding Brackets in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947930/understanding-brackets-in-dart)